# How to cancel the rendering in Rmd document when rmarkdown::render is called?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using `rmarkdown::render` to batch render some Rmd documents to HTML. The source documents contain several computing-intensive code chunks. In some cases, as the render goes, some variables suggest that the render should not go on, how can I cancel/skip the current rendering to the next one, if any?

In my case, the process of `knitr::knit` should be cancelled. How can I do that properly?

I notice that `knitr::knit_exit` seems to do this job, but I tried it in RStudio rendering and it does not work.

Comment: As suggested by yihui [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/344#issuecomment-8200067), you might try triggering in a chunk option, if you have a threshold parameter. This wouldn't stop it from knitting a file, but it would stop the evaluation of computationally intensive chunks, which, I gather, is your goal.